caseecade op-amp
what would the transfer function of this circuit, where R1=1K, R2= 560R, Rm = 240R and Rt = 530R. and what would be the output voltage. power supply of op-AMP is +5V and -5V.
let me add complete detail of project.
infact i am making pressure sensor datasheet of sensor IC is enter link description here
according to datasheet output should be like as shown in image

enter image description here.
i make same circuit my output behavior is almost same but the level of voltage is not same, i also try simulation on proteus8 but the simulation results are totally different from real results.


This appears to be duplicate of the previous closed question cascade op-amp transfer function. Consider trying to edit the previous question to add the requested details or clarity to allow the original question to be re-opened. This question is likely to get closed.

Link seems to be broken ...

The circuit as stated does not work.
Made with microcap v12.
You should change to this circuit.
The frequency can be changed by adjusting R2 or/and R1.
Note that changes must be "small".

